# What kind of objects are stored in large object heap (LOH)

Tags: c#, .net

Im aware that large arrays and strings if they exceeds 85,000 bytes will be stored in LOH. Is there any other data types can be stored in LOH?

Comment: Presumably any such type that exceeds this size. Why would you make one though?

Comment: Is there any background to that question? Are you investigating suspicious app behavior or what's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Anything big enough"

For example, you could use `[InlineArray]` in .NET 8 to create a `struct` that is absurdly big (I'm not saying that you should, it sounds like a terrible idea), and then you could put an absurd number of fields of that `struct` - or a "fixed-size buffer" of a large number of that `struct` as a single field - onto a `class`, and boom: LOH.

But... maybe don't do that. In real world scenarios, this is mostly just arrays (in particular large byte arrays and suitably big arrays of a non-trivial value-type), and very large strings.